# solve() execution aborted

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I'm having trouble using Sympy to solve an equation. When I run the code, for example:

`print(correction(10))`

I expect it to print a number which is f. Instead it gives me ERROR: execution aborted.

```
def correction(r):

    from sympy import cosh, log, exp, symbols, solve
    f = symbols('f')

    def equation():
        return cosh(((r - 1.0)/(r + 1.0))*(log(2.0)/f)) - 0.5*exp(log(2.0)/f)

    correction = solve(equation(),f)
    return correction
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Sound like you are running into some time or memory limit. If I try this with `r != 0`, this just sits, consuming CPU with growing memory use for the backtracker. Or in conclusion: `sympy` searches itself to death.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation is highly non-linear and my guess is that a closed-form solution cannot be found. That's why `sympy.solve` fails. The only option you have is to solve the equation numerically. Sympy offers the `nsolve` function for this purpose, which, as typical in numerical solvers, requires an estimate of the solution.

```
import sympy as sp
r, f = sp.symbols('r, f')
expr = sp.cosh(((r - 1)/(r + 1))*(sp.log(2)/f)) - sp.Rational(1,2)*sp.exp(sp.log(2)/f)

sol = sp.nsolve(expr.subs({r:10}), f, 0.5)
print(sol)
```

> `0.699259455239414`

Comment: Clever, as always. And how did you choose 1/2?

Comment: @BillBell Simply plotted the function and spotted a zero near that point :)

Comment: Can you please explain what the `sp.Rational` and `expr.subs({r:10})` parts are for? I haven't come across these before.

Comment: @EmmaSmith  `sp.Rational(a,b)` defines a rational number `a/b` in Sympy. The `subs({r:10})` method substitutes every instance of symbol `r` in `expr` with `10`. Please see the Sympy documentation for further details. Note, however, that these elements of the code are not essential for the answer.